# Destroying PersistentActor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

*a question related to Akka Persistence 2.3.10*

Is there a simple way to gracefully stop `PersistentActor` when it is no longer required? Currently, I manually delete all journal messages and snapshots from within an actor on receiving a custom termination message, but is there any out-of-the-box functionality for this?

Comment: Are you deleting messages and snapshots with `deleteMessages(lastSequenceNr)` and `deleteSnapshots(SnapshotSelectionCriteria(maxSequenceNr = lastSequenceNr))`?

Comment: It looks like that is already the best way to do it